# Enable Performance Profiler Output

Tags: performance-profiling

I've been searching a good bit on Google and can't find an answer.

I'm accustomed to using the Profiler output to determine which controls are under performing and optimizing them. Usually I turn these on by logging in and hitting the page using the ?sc_prof=1, sc_trace=1, sc_debug=1 query string parameters.

On most of my sites, this enables the Profile output at the bottom of the page.

But on one of them, I get nothing.

Is there a control I need to include in the layout, or a setting in the configuration files that enables the profiler?

So far I've,

- ensured I was logged in
- compared the layout aspx files between a working site and the non-working site, but did not see anything that jumped out
- compared the site configuration for the working site and the non-working site, but didn't see anything
- searched App_Config for "profiling" and "profile" and "debug" but didn't see anything promising

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Looked in /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx to see the fully merged configuration and saw that the working site had additional attributes on the site node.

I added the following attributes to the other site nodes:

- allowDebug="true"
- enableDebugger="true"

Apparently I was doing a case-sensitive search when I was grepping for "debug" in the configuration earlier. *FACEPALM*